# How to group data of similar survey answers with Power Query

Tags: excel, csv, powerquery, csv-import

First of all I'm sorry if I do anything wrong! This is my first post here, but I try my best.

To my problem: I have a `.CSV` file from a survey tool, which I try to convert in a more concise form with the Power Query Tool from Excel.

After some basic editing I get to a form like this:

Starting form:

[image: Starting form]

The left column reflects the headings of the questions asked in the survey. Since some questions can have more than one answer, the headings may appear more than once. My goal now would be: To generate a column for each question and to arrange the given answers underneath. But so far I get e.g. for "Instrument(s)" also 3 columns, because 3 answers were given there, I would like to summarize these also in one cell for each participant. In addition, after the question "comment" the evaluation of the next participant begins, so here should also start a new row. The target format should look like this:

**Final Format**
[image: Final format]

Do you have any advice or solution how to achieve this?
Thank you for your help in advance, I appreciate any help!

Comment: This is not a free coding site (although some might do that). But we can help you with code you are trying to develop.  This type of problem has been addressed on this site in the past. So please do some research and **edit your question** to present the code you have tried; along with an explanation of where you have run into problems.  In general, you can use an `Index` column; and then an `Integer/Divide` column to create a column by which you can group the different responders. Then it's just a matter of splitting out the desired columns in the `Table.Group` operations.

Answer (score 1):

In general, agree with Ron's comments

That said, some code samples were appreciated when I started, so here you go

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
// 20 based on number of repeating rows in each answer block
#"Divide" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Index",{{"Index", each Number.IntegerDivide(_, 20), type number}}),
// combine rows that have same title and more than one answer
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Divide", {"voteOptionText", "Index"}, {{"Data", each Text.Combine([voteAnswer]," "), type text}}),
// pivot to get into proper sideways format
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Grouped Rows", List.Distinct(#"Grouped Rows"[voteOptionText]), "voteOptionText", "Data")
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```